# Massive font declaration

Tags: css, validation, sass, font-face

Im just looking at some code that I have inherited and there is a font declaration in the CSS that is huge (I even had to delete the size of it to share here)!

Can someone please explain what this is doing? And also it is not validating when I try and compile the SASS. Is there a better way to achieve loading this font? Or making it compile?

```
@font-face{
font-family:Framework;
src:url(data:application/x-font-ttf;
charset=utf-8;
base64,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) format('woff');
font-weight:400;
font-style:normal
```

}

Comment: Just look into `base64` encoding, basically it's not loading a font file, it converted the font to a string to save a request.

Comment: I see ... is there a way to reverse engineer this and just revert back to embedding the actual file? The problem is it looks hideous and fails validation.

Comment: I have used https://base64converter.com/ before to get .woff files  (also fonts) out of base64 strings, should work for a ttf